# Using ProGuard when the main code is in jar

Tags: android, proguard

I'm new with Proguard and I have problem with setting up project to work with it.
Problem is, that the main code is in one library and the "final" project is some empty project used for localization strings, settings only. Where proguard should be enabled - in library or final project or both? 
Structure is like this:

ActionBar,Roboguice... libs -> Main Library -> Localized Project (just resources)

Is there option to obfuscate only the main library? It will be more clear to keep one proguard files for one release of XX localized projects.

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to apply ProGuard to the final project. Shrinking, optimizing, and obfuscating the library beforehand doesn't have any added benefit, unless it reduces the library's size a lot, which may reduce the total processing time if you have many final projects.